# Exponential Function grows faster than polynomials as an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

**Question:** To show that exponential grows faster than any polynomial numerically, a student thought of solving the problem $min \ f(x) =  x^m -e^x$, where the $m$ highest even power of the polynomial. He uses a Newton method with step lenght 1 to solve this. Moreover, he thinks that if his claim is true than the sequence $\{x_k\}$ shall go to infinity as $f(x)$ can decrease as much as possible by increasing values of $x$. **What is the mistake in his reasoning, explain it.**

**Attempt:** First of all, I thought of showing for any $m>1$, $f(x)$ intersects the $x-axis$ by using the IVT. Then, since the sequence ${x_k}$ generated by the Newton Method should converge to a root of $f(x)$, it shall go to any root of this function not to infinity.

Note that Newton's Method algoritm we should use:

**Algorithm:** Given $x_0 \in R$, $k=0$ and $||f(x_k)||> \epsilon $,
 we calculate 
$x_{k+1} = x_k - \cfrac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$, 
and set $k=k+1$, return $x_k$.

However, it feels like I'm missing some points in this question. I'm open to any suggestion.

EDIT: I'm not asked to solve this! The question is given as this. I try to point out the errors in the formulation of this optimization problem in a formal manner.

Comment: What is a "Newton method with step lenght" ??? And what is "the $m$ highest possible even positive integer" ???

Comment: $m$ is the highest power of the polynomial, sorry. 
Newton's Method for univariate functions which depends on linear appromixation.
Algorithm: Given $x_0 \in R$, $k=0$ and $||f(x_k)||> \epsilon $, we calculate 
$x_{k+1} = x_k - \cfrac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$, and set $k=k+1$, return $x_k$.

Comment: Which polynomial ?

Comment: Thank you, I know what Newton's method is. But "with step lenght" ???

Comment: My bad, unit step lenght, I'm so sorry. Polynomial is arbitrary.

Comment: Grrr, there is no step in Newton's method !!! And no polynomial in your approach !!!

Comment: Well, the question is given as this. It is clearly erroneous. I'm supposed to point these mistakes in a formal manner. " What is the mistake in our reasoning, explain it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is an error in his reasoning since what it is said is: if the exponential grows faster than the polynomial, then the sequence is going towards infinity. But, he uses the converse: if there is a sequence that goes towards infinity, then the exponential grows faster than the polynomial. This is not a general property. As an example:
$$
\min_x \ 1/x - c \ .
$$
Maybe, if he added the fact that the minimum (actually an infinimum) is $-\infty$, it would have been OK, but still, there is no such result I am aware of and he needs to prove it first.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you are over-thinking this?

The common approach to the question posed is to use the everywhere-convergent power series expansion of $e^x$ and argue that for positive real $x$ each power of $x$ in a polynomial is eventually dominated by a higher power occurring in the power series.

Your claim is true that $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x$ grows, but it is hard to see how Newton-Raphson helps reach this conclusion - it is a method for finding zeros.

Comment: I'm sorry replaced "we" with "he". I'm not asked to show that exponential grows faster than any polynomial, taking limit of $e^x$ over $x^n$ is a better approach I know. The problem is that a random person tries to show this numerically and came up with this reasoning. I'm asked to find  the errors in his formulation/reasoning.

Comment: OK - I doubt a numerical approach can * prove * that $e^x$ grows faster than  any $x^n.$   Some of the questionable points in the outline above have been picked up by other comments.  These are: what does the highest even power $x^m$ mean;  how does Newton-Raphson apply to this question if it converges at all (and the comments in the *Attempt* section are correct);  there is no minimum to the stated function $f(x)$.  Perhaps you should ask the student to clarify what he or she had in mind.